# JComboBox custom renderer is ugly compared to original renderer in GUI

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jung

I am working with JUNG and I have designed a custom renderer on the basis of the [Show Layouts example](http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/showlayouts.html)... everything is fine in selecting the layouts, but I have to admit that the custom renderer produces a really ugly combo box compared to other jcombobox in my GUI with their original renderer (I use Swing along with NetBeans 7.0). Here's the code for the custom renderer:

```
class ComboBoxRenderer extends javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer {

    public ComboBoxRenderer() {
       super();
       setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value instanceof Class) {
            String valueString = value.toString();
            valueString = valueString.substring(valueString.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            setText(valueString);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Is there something I can add to my code in order to maintain the same beautiful style of the original renderers?

Best regards,
Simone

Comment: Why are using `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer please why ???, there are differencies (from your or my view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer` which has its own decorations.

Try to use `DefaultListCellRenderer` and it will be look pretty, same as your others boxes.

`class ComboBoxRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer`

Comment: Ok, seems I got what was wrong... No matter if I used BasicComboBoxRenderer or DefaultListCellRenderer, the result was ugly (and the same)... I managed to turn back to the Acqua style by unchecking the final static checks for the jcombobox... that did the trick.

Thank you, Simone

Answer (score 3):

Extend a [`DefaultListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) instead.